# ax.text2d in python (Matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, text

I am using text2d() to write some information on the bar3d-Diagram.
The piece of code is this one:

```
textstr = '\n'.join((
        '{}'.format(langbezeichnung),
        'Beprobung {} - {}'.format(datum_start, datum_end),
        '{} Messstellen'.format(anzahl_mst_para),
        "BG          = {} µg/L".format(bestimmungsgrenze),
        "75% SW = {} µg/L".format(warnwert),
        "SW         = {} µg/L".format(grenzwert)))
ax.text2D(0.645, 0.74, s=textstr, transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=12, ha='left', va='top', bbox=dict(facecolor='white', alpha=1, edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.2, boxstyle='square'))
```

and the result is like that:
[image]

but i would like to have the equal signs ("=") at the same line.
Could anybody help me?

Thank you
Rabea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Monospace font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) and set the space. The spaces will align in this case. Example...

```
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
textstr = '\n'.join((
        '{}'.format('langbezeichnung'),
        'Beprobung {} - {}'.format('datum_start', 'datum_end'),
        '{} Messstellen'.format('anzahl_mst_para'),
        "BG      = {} µg/L".format('bestimmungsgrenze'),
        "75% SW  = {} µg/L".format('warnwert'),
        "SW      = {} µg/L".format('grenzwert')))
ax.text2D(0.645, 0.74, s=textstr, family='monospace', transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=12, ha='left', va='top', bbox=dict(facecolor='white', alpha=1, edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.2, boxstyle='square'))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you .. is there any other font to use instead of monospace? I would like to align the text with "arial"

Comment: The reason for the suggestion was that monospaced would have same width for each character. You can check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monospaced_typefaces) for more options on this